# css global vs modules property specificity

Tags: css, css-modules, css-specificity

In my ReactJS project I have defined a property in my index.css file:

```
.container {margin: auto}
```

And in my component.module.css file I have:

```
.component {margin-top: 6rem}
```

On my element I add both classes (.container and .component).
It looks like the global property value has higher specificity than the local one. If I add !important to the local value, it overrides but I would prefer not to do so. Is this expected or have I done something wrong?

On the other hand, when I declare properties for elements in my global index.css file:

```
button {color: red}
```

and later style the same element locally in component.module.css:

```
button {color: white}
```

The local value has higher specificity (the button is white).

So for element styles, local values has higher specificity and for classes it's opposite?

Comment: Its not the specificity but the order in which the elements are loaded here. If two same property are being applied to different classes it is the order in which the elements styles are loaded that matters. The later one takes more precedence. You can think of it logically  since the first style is processed and then the 2nd style gets applied and takes precedence

Comment: Being said that can you add a minimum reproducible example to this?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply and leading me to the solution. It was indeed the order of loading of the CSS files. I forgot to mention that I had already considered this and tried to switch the order of the classes I point to:

```
const componentClasses = `global-class ${classes['local-class']}`
<Component className={componentClasses}>
```

to

```
const componentClasses = `${classes['local-class']} global-class `
```

However, this didn't change the styles applied.

The change that was needed was the order of which I import the global CSS file vs. the component which needed styling.

So instead of

```
import Component from './Component ';
import './index.css';
```

do this:

```
import './index.css';
import Component from './Component ';
```

Please forgive me as I'm still new to SO. For a minimum reproducible example, will this link do?
https://codesandbox.io/s/css-global-vs-local-import-order-0urhmm

In the index.js file you can switch the order of the imported App component and the index.css file to see changes in styling. I hope I'm not breaching any of the rules here. Thanks again.

Edit: Link changed.